# Keyboard Shortcuts not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in 2015/10/5 alongside windows 8. The keyboard seems to working fine except the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>alt</kbd> and probably other that I couldn't tell without those button. I cant even copy and paste without them. I tried changing the keyboard shortcuts in settings but everytime I try setting to <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>something</kbd> it warns be back saying "don't use <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>something</kbd>". Can anyone help? is it the layout or something?

FYI: all controls are normal in windows. Also, for a first timer Linux user this is too overwhelming, just encountered 5 errors in 2 days. This one is clearly major issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this bug by package attached in this post:

[read , download and install](http://4xmen.ir/solving-shortcut-work-in-non-latin-java-apps%D8%AD%D9%84-%D9%85%D8%B4%DA%A9%D9%84-%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C-shortcut-%D9%87%D8%A7-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B2%D8%A8%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%BA/)

In the Persian and English.